# The forge script 'test-list-resources' only list 10 items

Tags: autodesk-forge

The forge script 'test-list-resources' only list 10 items. How do we list all the resources? Besides the command-line script, is it possible to view all resource somewhere online?

And I found that it 's not listing the latest 10 items, it lists the first 10 items after sorting by the **URN**(which is very long and human-unreadable), this is not so intuitive in usability, because usually user upload the model and could forget the URN and they might want to check the URN by executing this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please clarify where the `test-list-resource` script came from?

Also from my perspective this script under the hood use one of the next methods:

1.[Get Buckets](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-GET/)

2.[Get Bucket by Key](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET/)

Both of them them you can use for getting bucket(s) with content. And for both of them you can specify `limit` as Query String Parameter, and now you have 10 because this value GET methods use by default. To getting more them 10 you just need to set higher value up to 100(max value)

**Updated**

After checking script source I found that we use second of GET methods - [Get Bucket by Key](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET/). And the quickest solution that I can propose to you - is just jump in script code and edit 1 line. Basically you need only add limit param to query (for GET buckets/:bucketKey/objects curl request). And you can do this in few ways:

1. Hardcode 'limit' equal 100 

   `response=$(curl -H "Authorization: ${bearer}" -X GET ${ForgeHost}/oss/v2/buckets/${bucket}/objects?limit=100 -k -s)`
2. Pass value to script from shell environment variables
   first
   `export BUCKET_LIMIT=<<YOUR LIMIT VALUE>>`
   then
   `response=$(curl -H "Authorization: ${bearer}" -X GET ${ForgeHost}/oss/v2/buckets/${bucket}/objects?limit=$BUCKET_LIMIT -k -s)`
3. If you run script with 'sh' command you can add inline parameter
   first
   `response=$(curl -H "Authorization: ${bearer}" -X GET ${ForgeHost}/oss/v2/buckets/${bucket}/objects?limit=$1 -k -s)`
   then
   `sh test-list-resources 100`

Also thank you for notice this case, I will connect with script's author and create proposal for adding new functionality regarding limits and other params

Comment: It is a tool from forge scene preparation: http://forgetoolkit.com/#/scenePrepration

Comment: I have updated my answer with new information, check it please, hope you will find it useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did #3, now it's able to list all resources. :-)